# Different Flavors use different repositories

Tags: android, gradle, jwplayer

Is there a way to have each of the flavors of the app use different repositories? 
i.e.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'amazon repo'} 
    maven { url 'google repo'}
}
productFlavors {
 google {
 }
 amazon {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

found that you can add repositories inside the flavors.

```
productFlavors {
 google {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'google repo'} 
  }
 }
 amazon {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'amazon repo'} 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't solve my problem with this solution, since I can't add productFlavors in build.gradle in the root.