# Can we organize repositories by flavor and build variant

Tags: android, artifactory, variant, android-flavors

I am taking over an android project which can be deployed in many countries. Right now I have a set of libraries on a custom Jfrog Artifactory server.

What I am curious is can I clone this library set into different artifactory repos (have same group ID and artifact ID) and use them by android project's flavor and build varirant.

Something like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        if(flavor == 'A') 
        maven {
            url  'https://example.net/repoA'
        }

        if(flavor == 'B')
        maven {
            url  'https://example.net/repoB'
        }

        if(variant == 'debug')
        maven {
            url  'https://example.net/repoDebug'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
productFlavors {
 A {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://example.net/repoA'} 
  }
 }
 B {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://example.net/repoB'} 
  }
 }
}
```

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788589/859277).